# return null when use the backing field

Tags: c#

i write this code for add in database .

```
public partial class Unit : UserControl
{
    private ProductUnit _pu { get; set; }
    public ProductUnit PU
    {
        get
        {
            _pu.UnitNicname = TxtUnitNicName.Text;
            _pu.UnitFaName = TxtUnitName.Text;
            return _pu;
        }
        set { }
    }
    public Unit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StructureMapDefenation.Container.GetInstance<IUnitService>().Add(_pu);
    }
}
```

i need to get `textbox.text` value with  backing field but when i need to add value in database this `_pu` is null .

whats the problem ???

Comment: You realize that you got `set {}` right?

Comment: Where do you initialize the `ProductUnit` object?

Comment: how can i initialze for this ????

Comment: Write the logic in your `set {}` method to save the value, currently it's empty and will be null as you can't set any value. And initialize with: `ProductUnit PU myObj = new ProductUnit PU();`

Comment: `private ProductUnit _pu = new ProductUnit();` But I don't understand the purpose of the field nor the property. You might as well do this in the method.

Comment: You need a public method to return the value of PU.

Comment: You don't write `private ProductUnit _pu { get; set; }`. It's a member and `{get; set;}` are in a Property.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `_pu`, which should be a field and not a property by the way:

```
private ProductUnit _pu = new ProductUnit();
```

I don't really understand the purpose of the `PU` property though.

You might as well create a `ProductUnit` directly in the event handler:

```
private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pu = new ProductUnit();
    pu.UnitNicname = TxtUnitNicName.Text;
    pu.UnitFaName = TxtUnitName.Text;
    StructureMapDefenation.Container.GetInstance<IUnitService>().Add(pu);
}
```

Comment: @kianoush: `pu` cannot be `null` in the event handler. `_pu` is not used in my example. So what do you mean?

Comment: The field Text of the label have value?

Comment: @Tarma yes . . . .

Comment: @kianoush: Did you initialize the backing field? `_pu = new ProductUnit();`

Comment: @mm8 yes . i do it

Comment: @mm8 i need to fill `_pu` in `get
            {

            }` .

Comment: @kianoush: Well if you initialize the field and don't set it to `null` after you have done this, it *can't* obviously be null. You can try to make it `readonly` in order to detect that you are not setting it somewhere else: `private ProductUnit _pu = new ProductUnit();`

Comment: @mm8 There is no way to create a new initialize existence?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public partial class Unit : Form // <--------- Try this
    {
        private ProductUnit _pu= new ProductUnit();
        public ProductUnit PU
        {
            get {return _pu;} // read only
        }

        public Unit()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           _pu.UnitNicname = TxtUnitNicName.Text;
           _pu.UnitFaName = TxtUnitName.Text;
           StructureMapDefenation.Container.GetInstance<IUnitService>().Add(_pu);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to change UserControl to Form.